# Выделение памяти в стеке

Tags: c, переменные, стек

Вопрос такой: почему при объявлении локальной переменной память в стеке под них не резервируется, а при объявлении массива резервируется. (gcc, Оптимизация отключена)

Comment: Можете дать какую-то конкретику? Почему вы так считаете, например? Конкретный код?

Comment: Да, вы код покажите. Не вижу причин почему бы компилятору не использовать регистры под переменные или вообще их не заводить, если они не используются, даже при "отключенной" оптимизации

Comment: @Harry      void main(void)
{
 int x,y,z;
 int v[20];
 return;
}

Comment: @Sokuroff, потому что вы не используете эти переменные. Поэтому и не резервируются.

Comment: @Sublihim так и массив v тоже не использовался, но под него выделяется.

Comment: @Sokuroff массив - это не просто переменная :-/

Answer (score 2):

Ну как же не резервируется? :) А как тогда [получаются](http://ideone.com/hyTyiF) их адреса?

```
int main() 
{
    int x,y,z; 
    int v[20];
    x = v[0];
    y = v[1];
    z = v[2];
    printf("%p\n",x);
    printf("%p\n",y);
    printf("%p\n",z);
    printf("%p\n",v);
}
```

Кстати, `main()` должна возвращать `int`, а не `void`, но это к вопросу не относится.

Словом, дело в том, что у вас они никак не используются. А стандарты требуют от программы только одного - чтобы она *вела себя так, как если бы делала именно то, что написано*. Она себя так и ведет. Раз вы никак не использовали свои переменные - она *может* (но не обязана) спокойно их удалить - внешне это никак не будет проявляться. Может оставить. Может одни оставить, другие удалить...

Стоит вам начать что-то делать с переменными - как они тут же появляются. Но даже компилируя приведенный выше код, компилятор вполне *имеет право* просто выбросить эти присваивания - потому что наблюдаемое поведение программы при этом ничуть не изменится.

Comment: в приведенном выше коде выделяется, потому что они используются. Я имею ввиду случай когда они не используются. Под массив выделяется, а под обычные нет.

Comment: Имеет право. Не скажу, что знаю стандарт на 5+, но думаю, что там нет ничего такого - для переменных не выделять, для массивов выделять. Особенности реализации...

Comment: @Sokuroff если инициализировать переменные при объявлении, то конечно память выделиться при отключенных оптимизациях. Но, если переменные не используются, то компилятор их просто выкинет, т.к. они не найдут отображение в AST. Локальный не динамический массив - дело совсем другое.